# How to pass a list of files to parallel command and execute downstream command such as samtools?

Tags: linux, shell, bioinformatics

I have a list of files which I want to sort and index ,i listed all those files in a text file.

```
/run/media/punit/data1/GSE74246/tophat_output/CMP_SRR2753096/CMP_6792.bam
run/media/punit/data1/GSE74246/tophat_output/CMP_SRR2753104/CMP_7256.bam
```

The above one is just a list of my data which i want to sort and index.

Now i want to use this command

```
 ls *.bam | parallel "samtools view -b -S {} | samtools sort - {.}; samtools index {.}.bam"
```

Meanwhile I have also files with

> .bam
>   extension such as unmapped.bam which i dont want to sort and index

How can i exclude those "unmapped.bam" but since i dont have those unmapped.bam in my list but still i wonder if i use parallel then would it take those sort and index...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls *.bam | grep -v unmapped | parallel ...
```

Comment: this helped me long time back